# TFS Rest API: parameter outcomes to filter test results is not working

Tags: rest, tfs

We have been tinkering with the TFS REST API. Our goal is to get test results from a specific test run and only return the failed tests.

In this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/results/list) it states to use the parameter "outcomes", but when we add this parameter the GET operation still returns all test results, including the passed ones.

We are using version 2.0, but we are unable to find the documentation specific for this version.

This is an example of our call.

`https://<server>/tfs/<collection>/<project>/_apis/test/Runs/<run id>/results?api-version=2.0&outcomes=Failed`

Any help on how this filtering works (or the definitive answer if this does not work for version 2.0) is much appreciated.

Comment: It might very well be the case that `outcomes` parameter arrives with newer versions of the API. As long as you added `tfs2017` tag to this question, I suppose you have this version of TFS installed, and it comes with API v3.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=vsts. You can try the same call with `api-version=3.0`. If it still doesn't work, then it is definitely supported starting from some newer version...

Comment: Thanks for your help @YanSklyarenko , indeed, we use TFS 2017 with the latest updates. I tried 3.0 and unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: It only works with 4.1 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on my side, seems it's not available for the previous API versions (Tested on TFS 2017 and 2018, both do not work).

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/results/list) mentioned with the `api-version=5.0-preview.5`, maybe it will be available on later releases.

However you can filter the test results by outcomes using PowerShell with the REST API, see below sample:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection", 
   [string]$project = "ProjectName",
   [string]$testrunID = 223,
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/test/runs/$testrunID/results?api-version=3.0-preview"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$results = $response.value | Where {$_.outcome -eq "Failed"} #| Filter the test results by outcomes


$TestResults = @()

foreach ($result in $results)
{

$customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "TestResultID" = $result.id
          "projectName" = $result.project.name
          "testCaseName" = $result.testCase.name
          "startedDate" = $result.startedDate
          "completedDate" = $result.completedDate
          "outcome" = $result.outcome
          "state" = $result.state
          "runBy" = $result.runBy.uniqueName
          "errorMessage" = $result.errorMessage
        } 

    $TestResults += $customObject
}

$TestResults | Select `
                TestResultID,
                projectName, 
                testCaseName,
                startedDate,
                completedDate,
                outcome,
                state,
                runBy,
                errorMessage #|export-csv -Path D:\temp\TestResult.csv -NoTypeInformation # Export to .csv file
```

[image]

Comment: @WietzeVeldf Have you resolved the issue by above answer? any update?

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution to filter -and sorry for the late answer-. We postponed the project due to other priorities but will save it for the future.